# Monitoring Gruntjs task runner using PM2, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, pm2

I've been creating an angularjs app and add the Gruntjs as the task runner for it..

so whenever I'm trying to run my apps I'll go to the project directory and run a Grunt task which is `grunt server`. the command consist of the following codes

```
grunt.registerTask('server',
    'start a web server with extras',
    function (target)
    {
      if (target === 'dist')
      {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
      }

      grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
      ]);
    }
  );
```

and I've got a new task from my project manager to control above `grunt server` using pm2.

so whenever the `grunt server` task got crashed it will be restarted again.. is that possible using pm2 ? since AFAIK pm2 is a production process manager for Node.js so I don't really know if it works with Grunt but I do know Gruntjs is installed using npm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've manage to do it.. and apparently the solutions was simple

first run the `pm2 ecosystem`, it will generate an ecosystem.json

and fill it with this options

```
{
    "name": "management-app", //this is optional
    "script": "grunt", // the script that will be run
    "args": ["server"] //argument of the script
}
```

after the configuration file of ecosystem.json is provided, just run

`pm2 start ecosystem.json` and voila ! the result is great ! starting to love this component !